# Howto access REST API methods without username and Password - but only with a token?

Tags: c#, authentication, token

I'm trying to access/call methods in a REST API with a token from c#/.net- but I can't get any response back. I have googlet a lot - but without any success :-( I am new to call methods via a REST API.

I have an endpoint and a token which I need to use for communicating with a REST API. And I need to GET, POST, PUT and DELETE data on the server via those methods

The output from the API is in JSON format.

Maybe it is simple - but I don't know howto do it.

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried the following solution - but with no success :-(

```cs
        private static async void DoIt()
        {
            using (var stringContent = new StringContent("{ \"firstName\": \"Andy\" }", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);

                    // 1. Consume the POST command
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, stringContent);
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //Console.WriteLine("Result from POST command: " + result);

                    // 2. Consume the GET command
                    response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var id = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //Console.WriteLine("Result from GET command: " + result);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    //Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you initialize `AuthenticationHeaderValue` with "Basic", which means Basic authentication based on username and password. If you have a token, you do it with:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

replace ACCESS_TOKEN with the token you have.

This is the most probable solution, but I can only guess here, as I don't know the API you're trying to access. If it still doesn't work, try ommiting "Bearer".

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I have tried to change to Bearer - but with no success :-( The error message is "{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Allow, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, RequestMD5
  Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 11:00:16 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.29
  Server: (Ubuntu)
  Content-Length: 0
}}"

Comment: @MichaelEriksen And without "Bearer", just the token? See my edited answer, I can only guess. It could also be "JWT" (if you got a JWT token)

Comment: I have tried your edited answer too with no success :-(

Comment: The token is just a normal token - and not a JWT token.

Comment: problem is, I have no information about the API. I can say "Basic" is wrong, but beside that it could be anything. The HTTP error 401 also just tells you that authorization failed, but not why. It could also be an expired token. Do you have any more information abou the API. Is the token supposed to be any access token, and did you get it directly from that API, just before you tested?

Comment: "Unfortunately" I can only say that the token has been tested by the provider - and it is valid. And I have not got the token from the API, but only from the provider.

Comment: I can only recommend to ask the provider in this case. Maybe they even use a different header name instead of "Authorization" (e.g.. `X-Auth-Token`), or expect the token as a URI parameter, or whatever...   there are many different implementations.

Comment: @MichaelEriksen any news? Did you ask them or tried anything?

Comment: I have tried to ask the provider - but still no good news :-( I have also tried to google a lot - but until now I haven't found the solution :-(